# How to dump Python data into already made JSON folder?

Tags: python, json

I started to learn more about json and dumping data into a json file with python. My question is:
I made two json files not with python code (with open("randomFile.json") but I made the files 'with hand' and I stored one value to each file and loaded those values into separate variables.. Now I modified the variables(values) from json file inside a program and now I want to store or replace the old values with the new modified values inside these already made json files.. I hope this makes sense. Here is a simple example code..

```
import json

f1 = open('number1.json')
number1 = json.load(f1)

f2 = open('number2.json')
number2 = json.load(f2)

number1 += 10

number2 += 5
```

So variables number1 and number2 got the values from json file now I want to store these new values into the same json file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following valid json file called number1.json:

```
{
    "field": 1
}
```

Then, you can update it with the following code. Just do the same thing for number2.json:

```
import json
import os

file = 'number1.json'
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['field'] += 10

os.remove(file)
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, in this simple case, you can also modify without removing the file:

```
import json
import os

file = 'number1.json'
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['field'] += 10
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Why do you remove the file? I thought using "w" overwrites the file nevertheless? Or is it just to make sure?

Comment: I often find it easier to just remove it and recreate, otherwise we have to use seek() and truncate at the right places with just a raw dump.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you don’t have to use seek manually, it should overwrite it automatically as @MartinSteinborn said.

Comment: With the "with open" contect, the file should be closed after leaving the contect. Therefore if you open the file again, you should be at the tight position. Or?

Comment: Thanks @hysoftwareeng for the answer it helped me a lot!

Comment: @Martin Steinborn I believe you need to go back to the beginning in order to do json.dump? Otherwise it would append to the end?

Comment: ```python
file = 'number1.json'
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['field'] += 10
    print(f.tell())
# os.remove(file)
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    print(f.tell())
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Returns 
`
21
0
`

Therefore we dont need to seek and dont need to remove the file... Because the "with" does call close automatically:

```python
try:
    f = open("t.txt", "r+")
    # file operations
finally:
    f.close()
```

is the same as:

```python
with open("t.txt", "r+") as f:
    # file operations
```

Comment: Yes, but then you have to do two with `with open(file, "r+")`